# Cannot run Qt C++ release build. 'The procedure entry point could not be located'

Tags: c++, qt, dll, compilation

I am trying to deploy my Qt application and have run into a fatal error. The program works fine in the Qt editor, I can build and run it. After building my project in release mode and using windeployqt.exe to get the correct .dll's in the folder, I am treated to [this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWXxL.png). I get one for 5 different Qt .dll's. I found a way to remove this error by using the .dll's from Qt tools instead of the ones found in the compiler's bin directory. But, I am left with a [remaining error like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBBWp.png). Unlike the previous errors', there is no dll being cited, only my program's directory.

I've tried this with 2 compilers by now. That which is provided by Qt, and my own installation. Both you can tell, have failed.

Comment: It looks like that you are using windeployqt.exe from Qt build which is different from Qt build that you have used to build your application. That's why application crashes on startup.

Comment: Bumped into the same problem. Using Qt 5.9 to Qt 5.10, with vs2017. Only happens in Release mode. I had to move Qt dlls needed by program in same path as .exe . Quite weird.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem few years ago when I was just learning QT. What I tried which did worked is that to move the `.exe` generated file to the location from where you copy paste the `dlls` and it worked like charm. You are getting the wrong `dlls` copied (perhaps). Try searching for correct ones on google!!

Comment: May I suggest more formatting, and fewer exclamation marks :P

Comment: Yes, this worked flawlessly! I moved all the dlls from my Qt compiler directory and just waned my way through the mountain of dlls until I found which ones were necessary. Thank you shivam.