# GUI Expanded in C++ opencv

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, dll

I aim at using OpenCV3.3's imshow function such as image displays with status bar and tool bar, such as :

[image]

I'm using MSVC2017, so for that purpose I generated OpenCV's cmake with flags : WITH_QT and WITH_OPENGL and compiled the library.
It's working as expected with Qt5.9.1, but only in debug mode in my project.

In release mode, I get "Entry point was not found" for 3 DLLs :

- opencv_highgui330.dll
- Qt5Test.dll
- Qt5TestOpenGL.dll

I suspect some parts of the libraries are compiled differently, but I have no clue where the problem could come from. Specially since it's working in debug mode.

Problem remains when using either msvc2015 or msvc2017 compilation of Qt. Also tried Qt5.4 as a desperate move. Unsuccessfull. Any hint will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed dlls had to be copied in the same directory as executable in release mode.

Also see : [Cannot run Qt C++ release build. 'The procedure entry point could not be located'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42362250/cannot-run-qt-c-release-build-the-procedure-entry-point-could-not-be-located/42362464#42362464)